# CircularNotchedRectangle() is not working properly

Tags: flutter

The `CircularNotchedRectangle()` is not working properly. there is no cutout in the bottom app bar why this is happening, why bottom app bar taking default padding? is it supposed to have no padding(I used zero padding)?

the Image:
[image]

The `CircularNotchedRectangle()` shows this white shape at the bottom of the screen. if I increase notchMargin: 0.0-> notchMargin: 100.0 the white shape gets closer to the bottom bar if I increase it more, then the shape disappears (hides behind the bottom app bar).

The Code::

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            bottom: 20,
            right: screenWidth/2.85,
            child: Container(
              height: screenHeight*0.15,
              width: screenWidth*0.3,
              child: FloatingActionButton.large(
                onPressed: (){},
                tooltip: 'Start Engine',
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'Assets/Images/Start Engine.png',
                  width: screenWidth*0.28,
                  height: screenWidth*0.28,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                elevation: 0.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        elevation: 5,
        height: screenHeight * 0.08,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        notchMargin: 0.0,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(5),
            topRight: Radius.circular(5),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: screenWidth / 3,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(25, 192, 122, 1),
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.025,
                      width: screenWidth * 0.04,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.home,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onPressed: () {
                          *//*Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ));*//*
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Home',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontFamily: 'default',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color.fromRGBO(25, 192, 122, 1),
                  border: Border(
                    left: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 1.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                width: screenWidth / 3,
                height: screenHeight * 0.9,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: screenHeight * 0.01,
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: Text(
                        'Start Engine',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontFamily: 'default',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color.fromRGBO(25, 192, 122, 1),
                    border: Border(
                      left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                width: screenWidth / 3,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.025,
                      width: screenWidth * 0.04,
                      child: IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.info,
                          size: 20,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onPressed: () {
                          *//*Navigator.push(context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ));*//*
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Information',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontFamily: 'default',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@akhil-ge0rge/how-to-create-a-notched-bottom-navigation-bar-flutter-39b571afd570

Comment: I tried. Still, the notch is corrupted like in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `clipBehavior` to non null in `BottomAppBar` in order to clip the bottom bar at all.

Second you should remove `Stack` and `Positioned` from `floatingActionButton`. they make the button very large, thus make clip area larger than intended. You don't need them to place the button at center bottom.

Additionally calculating layout using screen size is not the best practice. Your first choice should be using Widget such as `Flexible` for evenly dividing `Row` and `Columns`